what changes when I change from Java 7 -> Java 8 or Java 8 -> 11 in my android project?
All I want is some understand what does it mean when we do this in our Android project.
Question 1.
In my build.gradle, if I replace
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
with
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
what changes? please explain In case im using only Kotlin and 2nd when im using both kotlin +java in my project.
Any performance implications?

Any portability implications (my min SDK version is 21)?

Any exotic new APIs that I get access to?

I can't find anything useful on https://developer.android.com regarding this.
Question 2: Please see the image attached, what happens when i change my or select any jdk verison there, where is that jdk being used?

Also what are these various types of sdk that i see there ? if someone can explain mein that please that be great.


I wasn't that person but I can observe that the first question lacks context of what you already researched. You are expected to research before asking. A Google search would return some relevant results. Read [ask]. That there is a second question indicates that there is a lack of focus. Read needs more focus.

And don't use rude language, in questions nor comments.

Answer 1: Source and Target Compatibility.
sourceCompatibility defines the maximum Java version of our source code will support. This means if we define sourceCompatibility to Java 11, our source files can use features up to Java 11.
targetCompatibility defines what version of Java the output (the bytecode) will have. Therefore, this value represents the minimum Java version that the consumer of your project (The device that will run our project) will need to run it.
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

This means, our source file can use features up to Java version 8. After compilation, the output bytecode will have Java version 8.
For more read this article.
Answer 2: JDK
Well, JDK plays the most important role in Andoird's app development. Whether your source code is written in Java, Kotlin, or both, there are several places you must choose a JDK or Java language version for your build.
But In the First image, You are not using JDK. You are using JBR (JetBrains Runtime).
The JetBrains Runtime (JBR) is an enhanced JDK, distributed with Android Studio. It includes several optimizations for use in Studio and related JetBrains products, but can also be used to run other Java applications.
In Android, JDK is indirectly connected with AGP (Android Gradle Plugin).
If you change the JDK version, Make sure to choose a JDK version that is higher than or equal to the JDK versions used by plugins that you use in your Gradle build.
For example, you choose JDK 11 and the Android Gradle Plugin version 8.x requires JDK 17. If you try to run a Gradle build that uses it with an earlier version - JDK 11, it shows the errors.
For more read this official Android documentation.
Answer 3: Verious SDKs
You are showing various types of SDK in the 2nd image. Well, They are JDK, not SDK. You have downloaded many JDKs, but honestly, I preferred to remove unnecessary JDKs and keep some of them like JDK 1.8, JDK 11, and JDK 17.
I hope this helps you well.
